# How to fix "Error: the locale requested by the environment is invalid" during postgresql cluster upgrade (pg_upgradecluster)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, locale, ubuntu-16.04

After an upgrade from Ubuntu Server 14.04 to 16.04 I had to also upgrade my Postgres clusters from 9.3 to 9.5. The normal way to do that is to first drop the (empty) 9.5 cluster that the upgrade created:

# pg_dropcluster 9.5 main

and then to upgrade the old 9.3 cluster to 9.5:

# pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main

This however results in an error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_PAPER = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_ADDRESS = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_MONETARY = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_NUMERIC = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_TELEPHONE = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_IDENTIFICATION = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_MEASUREMENT = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_TIME = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LC_NAME = "nl_NL.UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

This means I could not upgrade to Postgres 9.5.

I checked all locale settings:

- the en_US.UTF-8 locale exists and is properly generated as checked with locale -a (it shows en_US.utf8 in its list)
- The file /etc/environment contains LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 and LANG=en_US.UTF-8
- /etc/default/locale contains the same setting for LANG, LANGUAGE and LC_ALL
- I can start Perl without any issue using "perl -e exit"

The error message is generated from the pg_createcluster script which is called from pg_updatecluster. But running pg_createcluster from the command line works just fine, without any issue.

## Workaround for the issue:

I used the following workaround to at least get the conversion to work. I edited the /usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster script, as follows:

- Find the code where it calls pg_createcluster by looking for the comment "create new cluster"
- That code consists of a series of "push" statements, ending in the suspicious line:
      delete $ENV{'LC_ALL'}
- Notice that this LC_ALL is *exactly* the variable that is unset in the error message.
- Comment out that delete comment by adding a '#' before it, then save.

This at least circumvents this problem and lets you run the upgrade.

My question: is this a bug in the pg_upgradecluster script, or is something else awry on my system?

Comment: Related article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49089099/perl-fails-to-set-locale-even-though-it-is-installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

had the same problem on an ubuntu 16.04 server. what helped in my case was to generate **all** the locales that appear in your listing of `$ locale`:

```
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
$ sudo locale-gen "nl_NL.UTF-8"
```

good luck!

Comment: Remember to logout and log back in to your shell session.

Comment: This does not work under Debian/Ubuntu, where `locale-gen` does not take any arguments. Ideally, you'd run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` there.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it was complaining about

```
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid:
LANG: en_GB
LANGUAGE: en_GB:en
```

So I `unset LANG` and `unset LANGUAGE` and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add an extra command: set LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

For me, I have followed many suggestions and still didn't work.
The script mentioned

`LC_TIME=en_UK` but it's totally unrelated so I ignored it at first.
Turns out this was the problem and doing "unset LC_TIME" was all I needed.

Posting here in case it happened to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

My quick way to disable that message: (macOS 12 Monterey M1 and above)

Open Terminal -> Preferences -> Advanced tab -> uncheck to Set locale environment variables on startup

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was SSHing into a server from my macOS machine, and I would run into this issue:

```
$ sudo su
# pg_upgradecluster 15 main
Stopping old cluster...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for start operation
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid:
  LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  LC_CTYPE: UTF-8
  LC_TERMINAL: iTerm2
  LC_TERMINAL_VERSION: 3.4.23
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

The issue was, apparently, the locale forwarded from my machine. The fix is to run this, and not `sudo su`, before runnign the `pg_upgradecluster` command:

```
sudo su -
```

This will reset the locale for the root user.

Of course, you should make sure that the requested locale (`en_US.UTF-8`) is generated, via running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

and selecting the right one from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this in fresh Ubuntu + PostgresQL install, after all those years.. either way, the solution is:

```bash
apt-get install locales
```